# How can i retrieve childfolder id for email using Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I get the folder id for Inbox as follows:

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox
```

The Inbox has a subfolder called Test and under that there is Test1 and under Test2 is Test2

How can i make a call to graph api to get the subfolder details of Test ?
I have tried:

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/Test
```

but that gives an error:

```
"Resource not found for the segment 'Test'.",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `/childFolders` to get the folder collection under the specified folder.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/childFolders/{test_folder_id}/childFolders
```

To get the id of Test folder call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/childFolders
```

Resource:

[List childFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-childfolders?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)